# I need help my CMD working not the same result

Tags: vb.net, curl, cmd, command-line

Finally

`` enter code here
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim arg As String
        arg = " -X POST -H ""Authorization: Bearer LINE TOKEN HERE"" -F ""message=TEST"" -F ""imageFile=@C:\charts\PIC.png"" https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"
        ShellandWait("curl.exe", arg)
   End Sub
   Public Sub ShellandWait(ByVal ProcessPath As String, ByVal Arguments As String)
        Dim objProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            objProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments
            objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ProcessPath
            objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            objProcess.Start()
            Application.DoEvents()
            objProcess.WaitForExit()
            Application.DoEvents()
            Console.WriteLine(objProcess.ExitCode.ToString())
            objProcess.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not start process " & ProcessPath & " " & ex.StackTrace.ToString)
        End Try`
End Sub ``

Comment: What is in `ex.Message`?

Comment: `ex.message` gives a default message like "Microsoft.visualbasic" if it has not been defined by the programmer. `ex.StackTrace` should actually be used here.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 : What are you talking about? `ex.Message` is the message describing the error that occured. `ex.StackTrace` indicates _where_ the error occurred, but doesn't tell you anything useful about _what_ the error is. `Message` only needs to be "defined" if the programmer is throwing the exception by himself, which is not the case here.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Thank you for information this is a new thing for me .

Comment: @VisualVincent I use both message and stacktrace for debug purposes, but the message may not give enough information. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 : Ok, good :). Because it sounded like you were telling the OP to _only_ use `ex.StackTrace` (which so happens that he/she now did).

Comment: @NadechKukimiya : Please note what has been said above. `ex.Message` gives you a information about the error, whereas `ex.StackTrace` tells you _where_ the error occurs. You cannot use _**only**_ `StackTrace` because then you don't know _what_ error occurred (you either need both `Message` _**and**_ `StackTrace`, or _just_ `Message`).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but, because of my current reputation, I cannot write comments.  I feel the need to inform you that blocked out codes in the image you linked are not properly hidden.  It is possible to read the top one.  I suggest you always use a completely opaque brush to hide important information.

I know that this is not how info is usually sent on StackOverflow, but figured that this guy's privacy is more important than convention in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you i add command in question and if u want a line token you can make from this link > https://notify-bot.line.me/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
        Dim prc as Process
        prc = New Process
        prc = Process.Start([YourBatchFileLocation])
        prc = Nothing
```

Or, you could also try the following:

```
        Shell([YourBatchFileLocation], AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting. try using `ex.stacktrace` instead of `ex.message`.

Comment: perhaps you need to add the full path to curl in your .bat file and then run it

Comment: I realize there is no error in batch file, however since curl is run by using environment variables what I am saying is that the path may not be translating over through vs. Therefore, you should try putting the full file path to curl in the bat file.